# What happens when you push two different current and voltage in same wire?

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, current, solar-cell

Let's consider I am running a motor with a battery and motor consumes 15.8V 1A (also assume it is constant and does not vary.)

Now I add a solar panel to its power source which produces 5.20V and 0.06A. What will happen next?

Will draw from the battery will go 15.8-5.2=10.6V and 0.94A from the battery and rest provided by a solar panel and motor runs at 15.8V 1A?

Or there is some other thing that will happen. Do I have to calculate it using Kirchoff's law?

Comment: can you push two different currents through a river channel?

Comment: stop thinking `motor consumes 15.8V 1A` ....... start thinking `motor draws 1 A  when connected to 15.8 V`

Comment: how is the solar panel connected to the circuit?

Comment: show a schematic for how you 'add a solar panel'.

Comment: For the most part, you cannot have two different voltages at a pair of points. When you apply 15.8V and 5V at the same time, the two devices applying the voltage will be forced to a single voltage according to the nature of the driving devices.

Comment: When you connect together two devices that are both two-terminal devices, they, in effect, negotiate a voltage and current that satisfies both of them. You cannot say that one of them fixes both voltage and current. The second device gets its say.

Comment: Battery +ve and -ve are connected to two terminals of the motor and now I connected the +ve of the solar panel to the terminal of the motor where battery positive is connected and -ve of the solar panel to the terminal where negative is considered. I want to if the overall power in the circuit will increase or not will the power provided by the solar panel be adding to the power of the circuit or not or will it decrease the overall power in the circuit.

Comment: Also, I have done this thing and I found that the motor starts drawing more power from the battery when the solar panel is connected this way. Before I started this I thought it will actually draw less power after power from the solar panel being available. I just wanted to check if I am wrong or did I do something wrong with connection or reading?

Comment: So you connected three things together. Did you use two ammeters at the same time so you know the current in all three branches? Or did you just measure battery current? Is it possible that the "extra" battery current was flowing INTO the solar panel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am running a motor with a battery and motor consumes 15.8V 1A (which
> let's assumes is constant and does not varies) Now I add a solar panel
> to its power source which produces 5.20V and 0.06A. Now, **What will**
> **happen next**.

What happens next depends on the characteristics of the solar panel. Since the battery voltage is higher it will force current into the panel. A solar panel can be modeled as a current source in parallel with several diodes, so the equivalent circuit looks like this:-

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8lT9r.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Since you defined the battery as putting out a constant 15.8 V, the solar panel *must* have 15.8 V across it. Therefore each cell in the panel will have 1.58 V across it. A solar cell has similar characteristics to a silicon diode, which increases its current draw exponentially as voltage rises. If the panel is eg. 6.3 V open circuit then each cell drops 0.63 V at 60 mA. At 1.58 V per cell it might draw 1 A or more (in addition to the 60 mA of solar current which it consumes internally), which would make it very hot and possibly damage it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the answer explained everything that happened with my model and why everything was happening other than I thought.